# Idiomatic way to combine strings via list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, idioms

Can you suggest a better way to combine strings from lists?

Here is an example:

```
[ 'prefix-' + a + '-' + b for a in [ '1', '2' ]  for b in [ 'a', 'b' ] ]
```

which results in:

```
['prefix-1-a', 'prefix-1-b', 'prefix-2-a', 'prefix-2-b']
```

---

The actual context is working with files and paths:

```
dirs = [ 'dir1', 'dir2' ]
files = [ 'file1', 'file2' ]
[ 'home/' + d + '/' + f for d in dirs  for f in files ]
```

resulting in:

```
['home/dir1/file1', 'home/dir1/file2', 'home/dir2/file1', 'home/dir2/file2']
```

Comment: this may be a question better suited to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For working specifically with file paths, use `os.path.join`:

```
dirs = ['dir1', 'dir2']
files = ['file1', 'file2']
[os.path.join('home', d, f) for d in dirs for f in files]
```

Comment: This seems like the most pythonic way to go about it (out of the answers below).

Comment: @frist That was my mistake. I corrected it in the original post.

Answer (score 3):

You can use list comprehension, `os.path.join` function and `itertools` module:

```
[os.path.join('home', a, b) for a, b in itertools.product(ddirs, files)]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about with [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

```
['-'.join(('prefix', a, b)) for a, b in zip('12', 'ab')]
```

As others mentioned, you should use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) for filepaths.

Answer (score 1):

You could use cartesian product for lists.

```
import itertools
for element in itertools.product(["1", "2"], ["a", "b"]):
    print element

# Gives
('1', 'a')
('1', 'b')
('2', 'a')
('2', 'b')
```

Then join them however you want.

Answer (score 0):

First one: `['prefix-%s-%s' % (a,b) for a in [1, 2] for b in 'ab']`

The second one could be the same way but you may want to use `os.path.join` to normalize for Windows:

```
[os.path.join('home', dir_, file_) for dir_ in ['dir1', 'dir2'] for file_ in ['file1', 'file2']]
```